# Before saving a new record, Hibernate deletes all the records of this collection in the database, and then overwrites the new one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm learning the Spring framework and doing the server side of the project. I have the following problem:

I have User and Film entities. They have a many-to-many relationship, that is, a User can select several Films, and a Film can be selected by several Users. When adding a new Film to List films in User, or deleting it from this list, when using userRepository.save(user) hibernate deletes all films of this user from the user_film table, and inserts a new list. Please tell me how it is possible to add or delete only the film that was added/deleted by request?

Here is part of the code for the Film collection in User:

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_film",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uf_user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uf_film_id")
    )
    private List<Film> films;

    public List<Film> getFilms() {
        return films;
    }

    public void setFilms(List<Film> films) {
        this.films = films;
    }
```

Here is part of the code for the User collection in Film:

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_film",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uf_film_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uf_user_id")
    )
    private List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
```

Here is the code for the functions that add and remove collection elements and store it in the database:

```
    @Transactional
    public UserModel addLikedFilm(Long user_id, Long film_id) {
        Optional<User> foundedUser = userRepository.findById(user_id);
        if(foundedUser.isEmpty()){
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found, wrong ID: " + user_id);
        }
        User user = foundedUser.get();

        Optional<Film> foundedFilm = filmRepository.findById(film_id);
        if(foundedFilm.isEmpty()){
            throw new FilmNotFoundException("Film not found, wrong ID: " + film_id);
        }
        Film film = foundedFilm.get();

        user.getFilms().add(film);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return UserModel.toModel(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public UserModel deleteLikedFilm(Long user_id, Long film_id) {
        Optional<User> foundedUser = userRepository.findById(user_id);
        if(foundedUser.isEmpty()){
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found, wrong ID: " + user_id);
        }
        User user = foundedUser.get();

        Optional<Film> foundedFilm = filmRepository.findById(film_id);
        if(foundedFilm.isEmpty()){
            throw new FilmNotFoundException("Film not found, wrong ID: " + film_id);
        }
        Film film = foundedFilm.get();

        user.getFilms().remove(film);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return UserModel.toModel(user);
    }
```

After adding 3 films with id 1, 2 and 3 on request, I get this:
Adding film 1:

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.user_id,u1_0.birthday,u1_0.gender,case when u1_0.is_admin = 1 then true else false end,u1_0.password,u1_0.registration_date,u1_0.user_email,u1_0.user_name from user u1_0 where u1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select f1_0.film_id,f1_0.film_desc,f1_0.film_duration_minutes,f1_0.film_imdb_rating,f1_0.film_link,f1_0.film_name,f1_0.film_year,f1_0.image from film f1_0 where f1_0.film_id=?
Hibernate: select f1_0.uf_user_id,f1_1.film_id,f1_1.film_desc,f1_1.film_duration_minutes,f1_1.film_imdb_rating,f1_1.film_link,f1_1.film_name,f1_1.film_year,f1_1.image from user_film f1_0 join film f1_1 on f1_1.film_id=f1_0.uf_film_id where f1_0.uf_user_id=?
Hibernate: select g1_0.ufg_user_id,g1_1.genre_id,g1_1.genre_name from user_favorite_genre g1_0 join genre g1_1 on g1_1.genre_id=g1_0.ufg_genre_id where g1_0.ufg_user_id=?
Hibernate: select g1_0.fg_film_id,g1_1.genre_id,g1_1.genre_name from film_genre g1_0 join genre g1_1 on g1_1.genre_id=g1_0.fg_genre_id where g1_0.fg_film_id=?
Hibernate: insert into user_film (uf_user_id,uf_film_id) values (?,?)
```

Adding film 2:

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.user_id,u1_0.birthday,u1_0.gender,case when u1_0.is_admin = 1 then true else false end,u1_0.password,u1_0.registration_date,u1_0.user_email,u1_0.user_name from user u1_0 where u1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select f1_0.film_id,f1_0.film_desc,f1_0.film_duration_minutes,f1_0.film_imdb_rating,f1_0.film_link,f1_0.film_name,f1_0.film_year,f1_0.image from film f1_0 where f1_0.film_id=?
Hibernate: select f1_0.uf_user_id,f1_1.film_id,f1_1.film_desc,f1_1.film_duration_minutes,f1_1.film_imdb_rating,f1_1.film_link,f1_1.film_name,f1_1.film_year,f1_1.image from user_film f1_0 join film f1_1 on f1_1.film_id=f1_0.uf_film_id where f1_0.uf_user_id=?
Hibernate: select g1_0.ufg_user_id,g1_1.genre_id,g1_1.genre_name from user_favorite_genre g1_0 join genre g1_1 on g1_1.genre_id=g1_0.ufg_genre_id where g1_0.ufg_user_id=?
Hibernate: select g1_0.fg_film_id,g1_1.genre_id,g1_1.genre_name from film_genre g1_0 join genre g1_1 on g1_1.genre_id=g1_0.fg_genre_id where g1_0.fg_film_id=?
Hibernate: select g1_0.fg_film_id,g1_1.genre_id,g1_1.genre_name from film_genre g1_0 join genre g1_1 on g1_1.genre_id=g1_0.fg_genre_id where g1_0.fg_film_id=?
Hibernate: delete from user_film where uf_user_id=?
Hibernate: insert into user_film (uf_user_id,uf_film_id) values (?,?)
Hibernate: insert into user_film (uf_user_id,uf_film_id) values (?,?)
```

Adding film 3:

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.user_id,u1_0.birthday,u1_0.gender,case when u1_0.is_admin = 1 then true else false end,u1_0.password,u1_0.registration_date,u1_0.user_email,u1_0.user_name from user u1_0 where u1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select f1_0.film_id,f1_0.film_desc,f1_0.film_duration_minutes,f1_0.film_imdb_rating,f1_0.film_link,f1_0.film_name,f1_0.film_year,f1_0.image from film f1_0 where f1_0.film_id=?
Hibernate: select f1_0.uf_user_id,f1_1.film_id,f1_1.film_desc,f1_1.film_duration_minutes,f1_1.film_imdb_rating,f1_1.film_link,f1_1.film_name,f1_1.film_year,f1_1.image from user_film f1_0 join film f1_1 on f1_1.film_id=f1_0.uf_film_id where f1_0.uf_user_id=?
Hibernate: select g1_0.ufg_user_id,g1_1.genre_id,g1_1.genre_name from user_favorite_genre g1_0 join genre g1_1 on g1_1.genre_id=g1_0.ufg_genre_id where g1_0.ufg_user_id=?
Hibernate: select g1_0.fg_film_id,g1_1.genre_id,g1_1.genre_name from film_genre g1_0 join genre g1_1 on g1_1.genre_id=g1_0.fg_genre_id where g1_0.fg_film_id=?
Hibernate: select g1_0.fg_film_id,g1_1.genre_id,g1_1.genre_name from film_genre g1_0 join genre g1_1 on g1_1.genre_id=g1_0.fg_genre_id where g1_0.fg_film_id=?
Hibernate: select g1_0.fg_film_id,g1_1.genre_id,g1_1.genre_name from film_genre g1_0 join genre g1_1 on g1_1.genre_id=g1_0.fg_genre_id where g1_0.fg_film_id=?
Hibernate: delete from user_film where uf_user_id=?
Hibernate: insert into user_film (uf_user_id,uf_film_id) values (?,?)
Hibernate: insert into user_film (uf_user_id,uf_film_id) values (?,?)
Hibernate: insert into user_film (uf_user_id,uf_film_id) values (?,?)
```

I tried changing the cascade type and using EntityManager to save. Maybe I misunderstood something and used it incorrectly, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Why do you want to have a bidirectional mapping Film <-> User?

Comment: I would think that Films don't need to hold the whole user to it. Maybe should have a Reservation that references a Film and the User by both of their ID.

Comment: @ValerijDobler, I have a UserFilm class that has Film and User objects that refer to an ID, but I didn't know how to use it if I could make a many-to-many relationship.
I will try to do it.

Comment: You need to remove the join table from one side and use mappedby. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional